# Hide non child UIView in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I want to hide a non child `UIView` in a `UIView` but I don't know how to do it.

To be specific, I have a `UITableView`. Each `UITableViewCell` has another view inside it (a wrapper view called `wrapperView`). The wrapper has some labels set up in IB and some created programmatically. I have created a custom slide mechanism that reveals buttons under the wrapper (like the standard one does).

The labels created programmatically don't exceed wrapper's bounds because it clips the subviews. The problem is with the labels created in IB. They are the subviews of `contentView`.

How can this be solved? Is there a way for a `UIView` to clip other views on the same level(not parents nor children)? Or "transfer" the labels to the wrapper view?

Comment: "Is there a way for a UIView to clip sibling views"  No.  Organize your views better, so it works as you want.  Regarding the "labels created programmatically" I thionk your problem is incredibly simple - you should be making those a child of the other UIView - it's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what you're asking. A view will only clip it's subviews, not views that happen to fall within their frame rectangle but aren't subviews.

If you want to move a view object from one view hierarchy to another you can use `addSubview(_:)` to do so. That will automatically remove it from it's current parent view. To quote the Apple docs:

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and
>   that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.

Comment: My guess is the OP simply doesn't understand, that when you make a view "programmatically", you can of course set the parent, superview, of that new view.

Comment: I understand very clearly the concepts and I do know that a view will clip it's subviews. I was asking for a method to clip other views that aren't it's subviews. Thank you for your answer, Duncan! It works perfectly.